# php mailer settings function switch not working

Tags: php, switch-statement, phpmailer

I'm trying to make a function/switch for diffrent settings for the PHPmailer.
(something like this:

```
function create_mailer($current_site,$from,$from_name){

    require_once 'classes/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mailer = new PHPMailer;

    switch ($current_site){
        case 'site1':
            $mailer->isSMTP();
            $mailer->Host       = 'mail.site1.com';
            $mailer->SMTPAuth   = true;
            $mailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
            $mailer->Port       = 587;
            $mailer->Username   = 'username1';
            $mailer->Password   = 'password1';
            $mailer->From = $from;
            $mailer->FromName = $from_name;
            $mailer->isHTML(true);
            return $mailer;
        break;
    case 'site2':
            $mailer = new PHPMailer;
            $mailer->isSMTP();
            $mailer->Host       = 'mail.site2.com';
            $mailer->SMTPAuth   = true;
            $mailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
            $mailer->Port       = 587;
            $mailer->Username   = 'username2';
            $mailer->Password   = 'password2';
            $mailer->From = $from;
            $mailer->FromName = $from_name;
            $mailer->isHTML(true);
            return $mailer;
        break;
    }
}
```

In de index.php I've made something like :

```
require 'functions/create_mailer.php';
$mailer = create_mailer('site1','mail1@sitename1.com','mailname');
$mail = new Mailer($mailer);
$mail->send('mailtemplate/new_bid.php',['something'=>'else'],function($m) {
                $m->to('email@to.somebody');
                $m->subject('mailsubject');
});
```

When i don't use the switch the mailer is working.
(Iff the settings are just in the index.php i mean)
I cant figure out why this isn't working beacause i alway thought that this kind must work:)

please advice.

thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `create_mailer('sitename1','mail1@sitename1.com','mailname');` but are testing with `'site1'`.

Either add a default to your switch, or call `create_mailer('site1','mail1@sitename1.com','mailname');`

Comment: i noticed it ; and edited it, but in the "real" code this was not the isseu.
thanks for noticing it.

Comment: If you fix the example and test it, it works. Something must be different.

You could add a default in your switch and print the value of $current_site to see if it is properly initialized.

Comment: hummm strangly enough it does work now :S
I realy dont know what i did change but it works...
Properly it was a DNS update of the servers come to think of it....
thank anyway......